# find control name which caused postback inside nested update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a structure like this.

```
   UpdatePanel1
     |    |
     | CheckBoxes - in code behind CheckBoxCheckedHandel() method
     | 
     |---Usercontrol1
              |
            UpdatePanel2
                |
               Button1
```

Now here is the problem.

When I click `Button1`, it is causing `UpdatePanel1` to refresh and calling `CheckBoxCheckedHandel()` method. So either I want a control name which caused postback or I want to refresh only `UpdatePanel2` when `Button1` clicked.

One more thing I would like to say is I am displaying Time on both update panel to see if they are refreshing when something happens. At this time button1 click event does not refresh `UpdatePanel1` time but still it calls CheckBoxCheckedHandel() method.

I am stuck with this issue from last 2 days, please help.

Notes:
UpdatePanel1 - updatemode - Conditional and no triggres
UpdatePanel2 - updatemode - Conditional and asp:asyncTriggre for button1 click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the ID of a control that caused asynchronous postback. In your Page_Load handler put this code:

```
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        string id = Utils.GetAsyncPostBackControlID(Page, Page.Request);
    }
```

Following function gets the ID:

```
    public static string GetAsyncPostBackControlID(Page page, HttpRequest request)
    {
        string smUniqueId = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page).UniqueID;
        string smFieldValue = request.Form[smUniqueId];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(smFieldValue) && smFieldValue.Contains('|'))
            return smFieldValue.Split('|')[1];

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

ID of a control that caused postback is stored in a hiddenfield whose name is ID of a ScriptManager for the page. Value is stored in format: `Script_Manager_ID|Control_ID`

Answer (score 0):

To get the control that caused the async postback, you can use the following instead of parsing

```
var asyncPostBackSourceControl = Page.FindControl(scriptManager.AsyncPostBackSourceElementID)
```